# Windows 7 64-bit all memory used up after continuous use

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 64-bit Professional running on Intel [Core 2 Duo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors#Core_2_Duo_2), 4 GB RAM and nVidia 1 GB graphics card. The Task Manager shows only 3 GB of RAM, so I am assuming 1 GB is used by the graphics card. After I use the system for about 30 minutes, all of the memory gets used up and the system is responding very slowly. When I check the [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), the CPU usage is low, but the memory is above 95%.

I cannot identify the process which takes up memory. But this started happening after an update installed service pack 1.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the memory isn't just used for caching?

Comment: it can be a memory leak problem try to close your window gadgets for some time to see if it is a problem with any gadget. And if the problem solves this way then run your gadget one by one after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Use Resource Monitor (memory tab) to see if you can find the process or program using all the memory

All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Resource Monitor

or a run command

resmon

.
[image]

.